# How can I use org mode's folding mode in markdown-mode?

Tags: org-mode, code-folding, markdown

I am using `markdown-mode` on a git-commit message. At the bottom of a git-commit I append some lines to remind me what to take care. Example:

```
My commit message...

# *
# 1. `Separate subject from body with a blank line`
# 2. `Limit the subject line to 50 characters`
```

---

If possible, I want to use org-mode's bullets on a markdown file.

My goal is to use `# *` as a org's bullet indication. The reason for this is I want to hide some comments in the markdown but keeping bullet as comment as well.

commit.md :

```
My commit message...     | My commit message...
                         |
# *                      | # *  // collapsed
# notes                  |
# notes                  |
```

Comment: So you want to have Org mode-like folding in a file with a `markdown` major mode, right?

Comment: Yes sir, but I want to indicate the start point of folding using comment character, for example: `# *`

Comment: I think your title is misleading: you don't want to change bullet indication in `org-mode`, because the buffer is *NOT* an Org mode buffer at all. What you want is a folding mode that you can use in `markdown` mode.

Comment: markdown-mode already supports code-folding, nearly identical to what org-mode does. How does what you want differ from that?

Comment: BTW, you realize that `#` is not a comment character in Markdown, right? IIUC, there *is no comment character* - see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823468/comments-in-markdown

Comment: @NickD I am sorry for the false information, ah `#` is a comment character in `git-commit message`, I thought it was comment character in markdown as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you already have the [markdown-mode](https://github.com/defunkt/markdown-mode) and [poly-markdown](https://github.com/polymode/poly-markdown) packages installed and running in your emacs configuration file.

**MWE**

```
# headline

## level 2 headline 1 ##

### level 3 headline 1 ###
some text goes here

### level 3 headline 2 ###

## level 2 headline 2 ##
another text goes here
```

For some weird reason, code folding was not displayed in this GIF image, but I hope you get the point.

[image]

put the above in your markdown file and let the pointer be on the headline and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> repeatedly you will get the desired code folding. Use it for comments or anything you want.

**Emacs setup inside init.el**

```
(use-package markdown-mode
  :ensure t
  :mode ("README\\.md\\'" . gfm-mode)
  :commands (markdown-mode gfm-mode)
  :init (setq markdown-command "multimarkdown")
  )

(use-package poly-markdown
  :ensure t
  )
```

Comment: By default can it be opened as collapesed?

Comment: not quite sure what you mean, but if you mean like `#+STARTUP: hidestars` in the beginning of org files to hide bullet stars at the startup then no, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Yes sir `#+STARTUP: overview` is what I was looking forI . That's why first I want to keep org-mode but using `# *` as bullet indicator in the original question

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean, but I do not have enough reputation to comment.
Therefore, I will just write an answer here.

To add comments to a markdown file, wrap the comment text as follows `<!-- comment text -->`,
(see https://www.w3schools.io/file/markdown-comments/).
If you are using markdown-mode then you can quickly comment in/out lines/regions using `C-x C-;`.

The 'headline/org bullets' in `markdown-mode` are provided by [outline mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Outline-Mode.html). You can configure the 'bullet' via the `outline-regexp` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have used following trick, where TAB beginning of `#+begin_src markdown` line is able the wrap the comment messages:

```
My git commit...

#+begin_src markdown                                       
# 1. `Separate subject from body with a blank line`
# 2. `Limit the subject line to 50 characters`
# 3. `Capitalize the subject line`
# 4. `Do not end the subject line with a period`
# 5. `Use the imperative mood in the subject line`
# 6. `Wrap the body at 72 characters`
# 7. `Use the body to explain what and why vs. how`
#+end_src
```

as:

```
My git commit...

#+begin_src markdown ▾
```

in my `.emacs` config file, I have following lines:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("/\\.git/MERGE_MSG\\'" . git-commit-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("/\\.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG\\'" . git-commit-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("/\\.git/commit-msg\\'" . git-commit-mode))
(setq git-commit-major-mode 'org-mode)
```